# Setting compiler library search path not working

Tags: c++, linker, g++, cross-compiling, toolchain

I built a native compiler for aarch64. The built was successful. I'm having problems though, specifying the glibc (`libc.so`) library to link against. I followed the suggestion in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host), about compiling with multiple glibc, but is not working.

**The environment:**

- ARM 64bit machine.
- A toolchain in `toolchain_dir/bin/aarch64-linux-g++`.
- A sysroot directory in `toolchain/sysroot/lib`, which contains the lib.so.6 (glibc 2.25) and libstdc++.so (6.0.22) libraries and also the `ld-linux-aarch64.so.1` linker.
- The `/lib64` directory contains the libc.so.6 (glibc 2.17) and libstdc++.so (6.0.19), old versions.

**What I tried:**

1. I tried to compile a simple program as:

   ```
   $aarch-64-linux-g++ file.cpp -o out \
     -L/home/user/toolchain/sysroot/lib -lc -lstdc++ \
     -Wl,--rpath=/home/user/toolchain/sysroot/lib \ 
     -Wl,--dynamic-link=/home/user/toolchain/sysroot/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
   ```

   But I'm getting the error `"/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.20 not found"`. The error discloses that the `rpath` is not working, as is still looking into `/lib64` library, instead of `toolchain/sysroot/lib` which contains the GLIBCXX_3.4.20 (libstdc++.so.6).
2. Next, I moved the `toolchain/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.so.6` to `/lib64`, and compile again with the same command above, now getting the error: `"/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 version GLIBC_2.18 not defined"`. The error shows the new built libstdc++.so.6 trying to find the new built glibc-2.25, but is failing as is searching in the wrong directory path in `/lib64`.
3. Next, I set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/toolchain/sysroot/lib`. But right after setting this variable I get segmentation faults.

Do you have ideas why this is happening? How could I solve this issue? Thanks!

Edit:
Below more information from compiler, for g++ -v removed part of the output as is really long:

```
 $aarch64-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++ -v
 Target: aarch64-unknown-linux-gnueabi
 Configured with: --build=x86_64-build_pc-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-host_unknown-linux-gnueabi --target=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnueabi --enable-gold --disable-nls --disable-multilib --with-local-prefix=/home/common/userX/x-tools/HOST-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnueabi/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnueabi/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnueabi/sysroot --enable-long-long
 gcc version 6.3.1 20170109 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.23.0)

 $file aarch64-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++
 ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 4.10.8, stripped
```

Comment: 1/ Calling g++ with -v can help to debug such issues as you'll know how the linker is called. 2/ If I'm not mistaken --rpath has only an effect at run time, not at link time. 3/ I've no clue about your segmentation fault.

Comment: Do you have the same directory structure with `/home/user/toolchain/sysroot/lib`and all on the target computer? Run `ldd out` on the target computer, what is the output?

Comment: @n.m the executable doesn't get created as the compiling is failing. Also didn't mention above, for this environment, the host and target are the same machine.

Comment: Um, this is not clear from your question at all. Why are you calling it a "cross compiler" then?

Comment: Do **not** use `-lc -lstdc++` arguments.

Comment: @n.m Sorry for the confusion, I did mention though in the "environment" is a native compiler.

Comment: Sorry the more important question is, can you run your compiler at all? Does `g++ --help` work?

Comment: Uh, this is not a cross compiler then. Please remove this word from the question.

Comment: @n.m updated question with g++ -v. Also removed "cross compiler" as suggested.

Comment: @n.m tried without -lc -lstdc++ arguments and did not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189468/discussion-between-advsphere-and-n-m).